# Cron doesn't send e-mail with output of command (works from shell prompt)

Tags: email, centos, cron, sendmail

CentOS 5.5 x86_64

Trying to e-mail a periodic system update with the output of a system temperatures command:

```
hpasmcli -s "show temp"
```

Outputs something like:

```
Sensor   Location              Temp       Threshold
------   --------              ----       ---------
#1        AMBIENT              21C/69F    42C/107F
...
```

So, I script this:

```
#!/bin/bash
hpasmcli -s "show temp" > /tmp/monitorTemp.log &
wait
mail -s "temperature" me@mydomain.com < /tmp/monitorTemp.log
rm -f /tmp/monitorTemp.log
```

Set to run every hour in cron

```
* */1 * * * /root/monitorTemp.sh
```

I receive the e-mail, but it's empty. However, if I simply run it from the command line `./monitorTemp.sh` it sends me the e-mail with command output included!

What am I missing?

Comment: You can eliminate the temporary file: `/path/to/hpasmcli -s "show temp" | mail -s "temperature" me@mydomain.com` - the whole script on one line (plus the shebang).

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this:

```
hpasmcli -s "show temp" > /tmp/monitorTemp.log &
wait
```

to:

```
cd /path/to/hpasmcli
./hpasmcli -s "show temp" > /tmp/monitorTemp.log
```

When running from cron, you don't have the same PATH as when running logged in normally, that's something worth to keeping in mind. You can also change the PATH before

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/hpasmcli
hpasmcli -s "show temp" > /tmp/monitorTemp.log
```

or something similar. You can get the `/path/to/hpasmcli` by doing `which hpasmcli` from your regular command prompt.

EDIT: As Dennis notes in the comments, for simple scripts like this one, there's no need to `cd` or setup `PATH`, this would be just fine:

```
/path/to/hpasmcli -s "show temp" > /tmp/monitorTemp.log
```

Comment: Cool, glad that was the issue!

Comment: Yes, is there any $PATH at all for cron? It is another user?

Comment: AFAIK there is some basic path, but it's something like `/bin:/usr/bin` or something along these lines.

Comment: There's no need to `cd`, just do `/path/to/hpasmcli -s "show temp" ...`. For a simple script, I wouldn't change `$PATH` either.

Comment: @Dennis True, that would work just fine. I'll edit to note.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set a PATH explicitly in your crontab.

eg.
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/path/to/executable:.
* */1 * * * /root/monitorTemp.sh

But I agree that explicitly setting path in scripts is probably a better solution for one offs.